# Initialize Slick Slider by the image just clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I need a feature to finish my slider image. I've used Slick.js to build my slider and a little HTML and CSS to be displayed inside a modal that is fired up when the user clicks in an static image. Well, I need the first slide shown in the slider to be the one just clicked by the user. I think this is a very common feature in sliders of the world. But I haven't found the way of doing it after a lot of searching. I'm asking because maybe someone has used Slick before and he has had the same situation. I guess the setting I have to play with is initialSlide, but no idea how to store the reference of the image at the same time slider is initialized. I'm aware is a tricky problem but I'm asking just in case.Thank you in advanced

This is how I initialize the slider

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-gallery').slick({
      lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
    $(".slick-prev").hide();
    $(".slick-next").hide();
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(){
    $(".slider-gallery").slick('slickNext');
  });

  $('#next').click(function(){
    $(".slider-gallery").slick('slickPrev');
  });

</script>
```

This is the html of the static gallery image

```
<div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
<div class="main-img"><a href="#openGallery">
<img src="assets/images/2.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="thumbnails">
  <img class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 columns" src="assets/images/1.png" alt="">
  <img class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 columns" src="assets/images/2.png" alt="">
  <div class="thumbnail-hover"><a href="#openGallery">
    <div class="hover-gallery">23fotos</div>
    <img class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 columns" src="assets/images/3.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this the html of the slider

```
<div id="openGallery" class="item-gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close-gallery">X</a>
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 columns">
      <button class="button-slider-gallery previous-button fa fa-chevron-left" id="prev" value="prev"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 medium-10 columns">
      <div class="slider-gallery">
        <div class="image">
          <img id="image-slider" class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img id="image-slider" class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img id="image-slider" class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/3.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 columns">
      <button class="button-slider-gallery next-button fa fa-chevron-right" id="next" value="next"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls post your code as a working example in a fiddle. It'd be easier to help you there!

Comment: I would do it but I'be tried several tiemes to make fiddle work and I don't get it. And the code is dependent of external libraries. Honestly I'm not sure how to handle it. Because I'm depending on slick. but I will try

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is to use the slickGoTo() function attached to each click on image.

```
<img class="small-4 columns" src="assets/images/1.png" alt="" onclick="$('.slider-gallery').slickGoTo(0)">
<img class="small-4 columns" src="assets/images/2.png" alt="" onclick="$('.slider-gallery').slickGoTo(1)">
```

Notes:

1. The first slide is 0, the second is 1 and so...
2. You are using Foundation which is awesome. You don't need to add medium-4 and large-4 as you did when you have small-4. The Foundation rule is that "small" = small and larger.

If this is not working try the following syntax instaed:

```
onclick="$('.slider-gallery').slick('slickGoTo', 0);"
```

This depends on the slick version you're using.